# os x creating desktop app to show rtsp stream

Tags: macos, desktop, rtsp

I'm new on OS X.
I've never programmed in Objective C or Swift.
I want to create a desktop app with the following features:

1. Read a rtsp stream from a DVR and show the video on a window (Up to 64 images). I know how to do this with VLC WebPlugin.
2. Need to be sure that I'm using hardware acceleration. I have a Mac Pro.

My question

Which is the best combination on software (vlc, avplayer, c++, swift) for better performing?

I've been trying to develop this app with swift, objective c, QT 5 and I always get the same error:

> FigByteFlumeCustomURLOpen signalled err=-12936 (kFigByteFlumeError_BadState) (no provider) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-1562.240/Prototypes/FigHTTP/FigByteFlumeCustomURL.c line 1486

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use QtAV if you already experienced in Qt5:

[QtAV. A multimedia playback framework based on Qt + FFmpeg. Cross platform. High performace. Easy to use and develop](http://www.qtav.org/)

[GitHub - wang-bin/QtAV](https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV)